# What simple machine learning algorithm to use in POS tagging

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I am new to NLP. I have a dataset that has already a parts of speech included, the only problem is what algorithm to use in order to train my dataset. Sample:

```js
{"word1": "POS",
"word2": "POS",
"word3": "POS",
"word4": "POS"}
```

Ambiguity is not a problem in this case.
If I input a word, it should tell what POS it is, but if the word is unknown, the POS will also be unknown.